# Memory-efficient method for membership test

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Now I am researching parallel processing. The difficulty I'm facing is that the amount of data set to process in my computing is so huge that memory overflow happens as the problem size grows(exponential growth rate of the data set size according to the the problem size growth). My computing is online algorithm, where all input data sets are unknown at the beginning.

The main reason of memory explosion comes from data stored in hashmap(cuckoo hash used in my job). This hash map is used for membership test about the already processed data.

So I have been finding a way to make the memory usage smaller.

There are some characteristics in my case

1. The input and output are only integer value(0 ~ 2^64).
2. only membership test is needed(only "contain" and "insert" used).
3. But it should not be probabilistic data structure such as bloom filter(false positive never allowed)
4. The pattern of numbers of outputs are not adjacent but sparse(ex> 1, 16, 563, 711, 1221 ...)

I don't expect complete solution, but I would appreciate any hint or inspiring or information about related research or papers(I cannot find the related papers or research).

First of all, I am finding a way to reduce the memory usage. for simple example:
from 1 ~ 64 values are stored, I save the range data pair(1, 64) and delete the 1 ~ 64 values.(but this is not impractical in my case, as the number patterns are sparse as I state above).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Succinct_data_structure

Comment: Can you give a hint on what kind of algorithm you are trying to run?

Comment: @PMF analogically, this algorithm can be said to be find all nodes reachable from start node in the graph. To avoid duplicated visit, I mark "visited"(by storing node name(integer value) into hash map in my case)

Comment: The implementation of the hash map will depend on the particular language / library used. Maybe you need to write your own that handles a sparsely populated map better.

Comment: If an occasional false positive isn't an issue, a Bloom filter might fit your needs.

Comment: Howmany items can be present in the set at the same time? And:: are false *negatives* allowed?

Comment: @wildplasser The input data set size is determined by the number of cuda core threads. The output data set is a maximum of (the size of input data size * predefined small value(24) * 2 * a value determined by the program argument).

False negative is also not allowed.